# Laravel Route collection get actionList only

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to get all routes defined in `routes\web.php`. I have tried `dd(\Route::getRoutes());` However, `getRoutes()` method returns about four properties:

`RouteCollection {#25 ▼
  #routes: array:3 [▶]
  #allRoutes: array:43 [▶]
  #nameList: array:21 [▶]
  #actionList: array:41 [▶]
}`

The `actionList` is protected property. I need to know any method or any way that able to return only the `actionList`

Answer (score 0):

Till this time I could not able to find a method that able to get the protected property `actionList` so, I have tried to loop through the output of `\Route::getRoutes()` as the following:

```
$out = [];
      foreach (\Route::getRoutes()->get() as $r){
        if(isset($r->action['controller'])){
          $out[] = $r->action['controller'];        
        } 
      }
dd($out);
```

By this way I have got the routes defined in the `routes\web.php` only. Where the length of the array generated `$out` is equals to the length of `actionList` array regarded in the question,*in my case 41*.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this I think.

```
    $routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeCollection as $value) {
    echo $value->getPath();
}
```

Comment: I don't want the path.

Comment: What you want? Route names? or something else?

Comment: No, not the route name, Indeed, the controller and action full namespace, something like: `App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index` and this was defined in `routes\web.php` as `Route::get('/posts','PostController@index');`

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone who comes across this thread.

```
$routeCollection = \Route::getRoutes();

foreach ($routeCollection as $i) {
dd($i->getAction()) . '<br>';
}

getName() // get name
```

Reference: https://hdtuto.com/article/how-to-get-routes-lists-in-laravel-5-

Answer (score 0):

**This is the correct code for getting all the routes**

```
    $allRoutes = Route::getRoutes();
    $r = $allRoutes->getRoutes();
    foreach ($r as $value)
    {
        echo($value->uri())."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use `$query= Modelname::query()->toSql();` at the end of your query then

```
dd($query);
```

Try this. It will help you. Have Fun :)